# nodejs and sqs: image upload to s3 with post-processing

Tags: node.js, service-worker, amazon-sqs

I have a nodejs server in express where users can sign up and add a avatar. This avatar is - after uploading to the server - cropped to 200x200 px and some other image alterations with [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp). I want to optimize this process by adding a worker thread connected to amazon SQS. My strategy (please correct me if I'm wrong).

1. upload the file (raw) to an S3 folder without uploading it first to my nodejs server (so user --> S3 instead of user --> node --> s3).
2. adding a message to a SQS queue from nodejs with the payload message that a new avatar is uploaded to s3 (with the url of the avatar and the ID of the user in the json payload for the message).
3. Initiating a worker thread that listen's to the queue for new messages. It receives a new message and the worker thread will do the modifications to the file (cropping it, ...) and upload it back to s3.

I have a few questions about this strategy?

1. How do I add a worker thread to my nodejs server. I have a digitalocean droplet with 2 CPU's, and I'm using PM2 to spawn my nodejs server to both CPU's. How do I add a worker thread to this system? Or should I add a second server with this worker thread?
2. Can I do database manipulations in a worker thread?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: DO you mean worker thread instead of service workers in Node.js?

Comment: yes exactly, sorry for the inconvenience, I'll change my question.

Comment: Can't you use lambda for this type of processing? It is will be perfect for this use case. Also, how many Image alterations are you expecting per minute?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [BullMQ](https://docs.bullmq.io/) for these kinds of requirements, where you need to post-process a logic separately from your client logic.

To put it simply, you need a message-queue-worker system to post-process jobs. This can be achieved using many queue systems available, like RabbitMQ, or the one I mentioned earlier (which I personally prefer for NodeJS).